# How to display loading spinner in angular js

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using angular js, and want to define actions on a button that presents a loading spinner, then loads some content. I am trying to make correct separation between view and controller, but I can't think how to do it properly.

Currently, I am setting a variable in the controller, and watching it in the view - but it seems a bit long winded.

### HTML

```
<div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="inControl">
        <button ng-click="doIt()">Cool <i ng-show="loading">...</i></button>
    </div>
</div>
```

### JS

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

function inControl($scope) {
    $scope.loading = false
    $scope.doIt = function(){
        $scope.loading = true
        setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.loading = false
            $scope.$apply()
        }, 500)
    };
}
```

### Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/billymoon/4es3h/

What is the proper way to handle this scenario using angular js?

Comment: http://lemoncode.net/2013/07/31/angularjs-found-great-solution-to-display-ajax-spinner-loading-widget/ this may help

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty much exactly what I've done in the past.

Additionally, you might want to add some protection to stop double clicks:

```
$scope.doIt = function(){
    if($scope.loading == false) {
        $scope.loading = true
        setTimeout(function(){
            $scope.loading = false
            $scope.$apply()
        }, 500);
    }
};
```

If you're doing the same sort of button in multiple places, wrapping up the concept into a directive would neaten things up and allow you modify the underlying behaviour if you change your approach down the line.